# Почему COUNT(*) с WITH(NOLOCK) не работает на неподтвержденных данных?

Tags: sql-server

Собственно, вопрос:
Почему так происходит?

Например, я делаю `INSERT` в чистую таблицу и если делать обычные `SELECT`'ы с `WITH(NOLOCK)` в другом окне запроса, пока идет процесс вставки, то я вижу, как данные добавляются.

Однако, если попробовать подсчитать количество, выполнив `COUNT(*)`, то возвращается 0.

Вроде, `SELECT` выполняется в самом конце => он должен подсчитывать фактические данные, которые не подтверждены...

Comment: Можете привести пример?

Comment: [When you use NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED you are telling SQL Server you are not interested in consistency](https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx)

Comment: @PashaPash Просто, в одном окне запроса делаю здоровую вставку из одной таблицы в другую, а в другом окне выполняю COUNT с NOLOCK, но возвращается 0. Если данные возвращать, то они возвращаются.